# What domain is Google Cloud Storage expecting in the ACL definitions when inserting an object?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts

I am using the google storage API to persist and retrieve images from an app deployed on GAE. I successfully retrieve the images but when it comes to persisting I am getting error 400 with this in the details:

```
400 OK
{
    "code" : 400,
    "errors" : [ {
        "domain" : "global",
        "message" : "Required",
        "reason" : "required"
     }],
     "message" : "Required"
}
```

Based on [this information](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gs-discussion/400%2420json%2420domain/gs-discussion/3PaLoMXzmz0/bgGPjFarqBoJ) I thought I may not need it so I tried without. When I added the appspot URL I'm communicating with google cloud storage from I got this:

```
400 OK
{
    "code" : 400,
    "errors" : [ {
        "domain" : "global",
        "message" : "Required",
        "reason" : "required"
     }, {
        "domain" : "global",
        "message" : "Could not find domain \"mydomain.appspot.com\".",
        "reason" : "invalid"
     } ],
     "message" : "Required"
}
```

I have followed the following steps:

1. turned on JSON API access to Google Cloud Service
2. created a service account
3. downloaded the p12 file
4. configured maven to not encode the file
5. configured maven to include the storage service api
6. created a GoogleCredential using the service account email address as the service account, added StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL to the scopes and linked to the private key file (p12)
7. instantiated a Storage object using the credential above, http transport, etc

I am using a List of ObjectAccessControl objects that get set on the StorageObject object like such:

```
...
//email from the service account client id configuration in the google cloud console
myAclList.add(new ObjectAccessControl()
            .setEntity("user-" + settings.getEmail()).setRole("OWNER")); 
//confused about what domain I should use; tried none, 
myAclList.add(new ObjectAccessControl()
            .setEntity("domain-" + settings.getDomain())
            .setRole("READER"));
StorageObject objectMetadata = new StorageObject()
            .setName("blahblah")
            .setAcl(myAclList)
            .setContentDisposition("attachment");
Storage.Objects.Insert insertObject = storage.objects()
            .insert(settings.getBucket(), objectMetadata, mediaContent);
insertObject.execute();  //400 error happens here
...
```

What exactly should I be sending for the domain? Am I missing configuring something in the console maybe? I'm out of ideas.

Thank you so very much for any suggestions!

**EDIT:** I am using the v1beta2-rev2-1.15.0-rc version of the google-api-services-storage jar.

Comment: By default, the ACL list should be set to a sensible default. If you try leaving out setAcl() entirely, do things work for you?

Comment: Removing the setAcl() yields the same result.

Comment: Actually the [ObjectAccessControls doc](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/defaultObjectAccessControls) says nothing of setting the domain as an entity, just the group or user while the domain is to be set if available, yet the example in the [Object insert doc](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert?hl=en) shows the domain being set as an entity in the ACL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing "Could not find domain \"mydomain.appspot.com\"." is that the "domain-" prefix refers to all accounts within a Google Apps for Business domain, not appengine domain names. For example, if you were using Google Apps for your company, fakecompany.com, and you wanted to grant read access for a bucket for all accounts under fakecompany.com, you could specify "domain-fakecompany.com" to refer to all such accounts.

I'm guessing mydomain.appspot.com is an appengine domain name and not a Google Apps for Business domain, which would cause that sort of error.

**Updates**: There was another misunderstanding that is worth pointing out. A service account does not necessarily have permission to insert new objects into buckets that you own. Make sure that it either has explicit WRITE or better permission on a bucket, or, if you're using the default bucket ACL, that it is at least an "editor" on your project.

Finally, make sure that your bucket names and object names are present and not null when inserting objects. This is a surprisingly easy problem to have, and the error message provided doesn't always make this very clear.

Comment: So all I'm trying to do is upload this object to the GCS and make it readable by everyone. I want to do this using the JSON API. Which ACL rules should I be adding using the StorageObject builder? I don't particularly care about any particular domain. I just want the owner to be set to the email provided with the service account (first 2 lines in the code above) and to make it readable to everyone, however I don't seem to be able to even set an ACL that has no domain (see first JSON error). Is it correct that a domain is always required? And if so, what should that be if the app is on GAE?

Comment: The ONLY two fields you should set in an ACL rule are "entity" and "role". To make the object readable by everyone, use an "entity" of "allUsers" and a role of "READER", and that's it. The account which uploaded the object will always be the owner implicitly, and attempting to change that explicitly is an error.

Comment: I removed everything but the allUsers/READER ObjectAccessControl entry and I'm still getting "domain" : "global", "message" : "Required". Any other thoughts? We're getting a Premier account so we can bug Google officially :) but the procurement process is going to take a month or so and I really need to get this going soon :(

Comment: Hrm...I don't think the ACL is your problem. Does logging provide you with the exact request being sent to the server? I think something else is going on.

Comment: Request
• "grant_type" -> "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"
• "assertion" -> "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5j .. a bunch more characters here...

Assertion is built with these parameters:
• "alg" -> "RS256"
• "typ" -> "JWT"

Payload:
• "aud" -> "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
• "exp" -> "1375463597"
• "iat" -> "1375459997"
• "iss" -> "email_address_generated_for_the_secrets_json_file@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
• "scope" -> "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control"

Comment: Are you sure settings.bucket() is a valid bucket name? If it's returning null, you might get that. And mediaContent is valid?

Comment: Yes the settings.bucket() returns the correct bucket name. The media type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34709/discussion-between-brandon-yarbrough-and-edlftt)

Comment: In conclusion: the name of the object was not being set (variable was null .. d'oh) and that's what the "Required" was all about. Because of the "domain" key in the json response I erroneously thought this was related to the domain not being set in the ACL.

Comment: In addition, I received a 403 .. I thought that a service account email address would be automatically granted full writes on all the buckets associated with the app. Those rights need to be specifically granted.